# How do I insert a Keras layer before previously defined layers?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm training an autoencoder in Keras right now, below is the network structure.

```
input_img = Input(shape=(target_size[0], target_size[1], 3))
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = 'same')(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = 'same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = 'same')(x)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation = 'sigmoid', padding = 'same')(x)
```

I'm having trouble thinking of a way to:

1. Insert an input layer between where "encoded" is defined and the Conv2D layer after it - the intention is to get the encoding of two different images, create a bunch of iterative "steps" between their encoding, then input these encodings into the "decoder" half of this network to generate an image for every step. I want to make a gif of the output "morphing" from one image to the other.
2. I wanted to try inserting another Conv2D(...) and MaxPooling2D(...) pair right after the input layer, and a corresponding UpSampling2D(...) and Conv2D(...) at the end. I had this idea from [NVidia's "Progressive Growing of GANs for Improved Quality, Stability, and Variation"](http://research.nvidia.com/publication/2017-10_Progressive-Growing-of) paper, where they trained their GAN to generate really good images at low resolutions, then progressively added more layers at the beginning and end of their network and trained the whole network with the new layers.

Does this make sense? Please let me know if I can clarify anything, I feel like this is very specific problem that's hard to explain over text all at once.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding question (1), can you please clarify it a bit more.
Regarding (2), what are the expected number of channels in the new layers that you want to add? I mean, currently in the encoder the number of channels are (8, 16, 32) respectively. If you want to add something on top of it, is it going to have 4 channels? If yes, continuing likewise, is there some threshold (like 4) for all the newly added layers, or you keep on decreasing by two times, until you reach some minimum number of channels (say, 2)? (On similar note, for the decoder part also)

Comment: @Koustav (1) I want to stick an "Input" layer at the beginning of the decoder network. IE, right before the second Conv2D(32, ...). This way I can treat this as a independent network and send inputs (autoencoder encodings) down to generate images

(2) You're right about how each new layer looks like it would have half as many channels as the previous. For now, yes, I would like the new layers to have 4 channels.

My question wasn't really about the # of channels, it's really about using a new layer as an input to a previously defined layer.

Thank you!

Comment: (1/3) Yes, I understand that #channels isn't the main concern over here. The reason for asking about it is, if you have some fixed formula by which you decide the #channels in a particular layer, then you can have a function, which takes as argument the number of layers you want in your encoder (and decoder), and creates a network out of it. For example, initially 3 in your above case. Once that is trained, you can save the learned weights. Now when you want to add one more layer, you simply call the same function with 4 layers as argument, and load the weights from the disk.

Comment: (2/3) So now you have the three already learnt weights and the new layer appended on top of it (for the encoder) and at the bottom of it (for the decoder) which gets trained from scratch. In order to achieve this, you need to have distinct names for each of your layers and while loading them, you need to set `by_name = True`. You can also further fine-tune you previously trained layers along with the new layers, or just fix their weight. Up to you. This not only serves your purpose easily, but also makes it generic to be used for any `n` layers that you want to stack in your auto-encoder.

Comment: (3/3) Let me know if it isn't clear to you from the description, and you would like to have some code snippet. Then I will add it as an answer tor your question. You can do similarly for your decoder too (1st part of your question). Under the assumption, you don't need joint training of your AE and your decoder. You train your AE and save it's weights.  You can make use of similar utility function (as stated above, but just for your decoder this time), load the corresponding weights (`by_name = True`), and use it for training or inference of just your decoder.